# What is $\frac{\partial A \otimes A^{-1}}{\partial A}$ in tensor notation?

Tags: tensors

$A$ being a symmetric second-order tensor. In index notation it becomes
$$\frac{\partial A \otimes A^{-1}}{\partial A}=\frac{\partial A_{ij} A^{-1}_{kl}}{\partial A_{mn}} = A_{ij}\frac{\partial A^{-1}_{kl}}{\partial A_{mn}} + A^{-1}_{kl}\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{mn}}$$

The first term on the right in tensor notation is obviously $A_{ij}\frac{\partial A^{-1}_{kl}}{\partial A_{mn}} = A\otimes\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}$, but what about the second term $A^{-1}_{kl}\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{mn}}$? I'm aware that $\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{mn}}$ is the symmetric fourth order unit tensor, but with $A^{-1}_{kl}$ having the two "middle" indices, it feels kinda awkward to maneuver. Is there a way to get this to tensor notation as well?

Answer (score 1):

What (kinda) solved my problem is the fact that in my specific application the second term gets double-contracted by another symmetric second order tensor $B$.

This checks out to $B:\text{term}=B_{ij}A^{-1}_{kl}\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{mn}}=B_{ij}A_{kl}\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}=B_{mn}A_{kl}=A\otimes B$.